# How to place 2 toolbar ribbons on top and bottom with TinyMCE 5

Tags: tinymce, tinymce-5

I'm new to tinymce. I'm trying to figure out how to add two (2) toolbar ribbons; one on the top of the page and another on the bottom on the page.

It looks like only one toolbar ribbon (div ? ) is supported.  I've search the documentation but only found info for fixed container CSS using inline config :https://www.tiny.cloud/docs/configure/editor-appearance/#fixed_toolbar_container

Can someone please help me out ?

Answer (score 0):

While [TinyMCE recently reintroduced multiple toolbar functionality](https://www.tiny.cloud/docs/changelog/#version508june182019), it does not currently support those toolbars being in different, separate areas of the Editor.

The `fixed_toolbar_container:` config option does allow a single, inline mode toolbar to be positioned, but multiple, separate toolbars are not currently supported in inline mode either.

Comment: Thanks. This is what I suspected, but was unsure being only days new into it. It looks like the toolbar definition sits is in CommonToolbar.ts. I'm not sure what all the alloy stuff is. 

I'm going to see if the context toolbar can provide a work around

Comment: The layout for the context toolbar is too limited for the time I have to work the issue. I'm going with a toolbar draw work around. When I have time, I'll add the functionality